# Apple App Site Association working in Postman but not for online validators

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

I'm serving the `apple-app-site-association` through https://xxxxxx/.well-known/apple-app-site-association

If you open the link in your browser or Postman you'll get the file.
If I use external validators like:
https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/ or
https://limitless-sierra-4673.herokuapp.com/
**It's not working**.

Previously I served the exact same file through an **NGINX** and the validation was **successful**.
(Currently I serve this file with a .Net Core App and in between is NGINX as reverse proxy)

Comment: Your site seems to have an IPv6 problem; Specifically it has an AAAA record, but is not responding on that address.  This will cause a failure for any device/app that prefers IPv6.  https://ready.chair6.net/?url=petmebae.serverlein.de

Comment: Thx for your comment. I updated my dns and server settings, to fix this issue. But still the validators aren't giving me a response. When I check the web developer tools one is giving me a bad request for my domain.

Comment: Ok I found the issue. I'm not giving the fullchain (missing intermediate certificate) at my hosting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that I'm not giving the intermediate certificate in my webserver/hosting. If I provide the fullchain.pem from LetsEncrypt it's working.